# Finding extremals of a functional with integral function as integrand

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, optimization, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

Assume you want to find the extremals for the functional
$$
y \rightarrow \int_a^by(x)\left[\int_a^xy(\xi)\, d\xi\right]\, dx
$$
where $[a,b]\subset \mathbb{R}$ and $y\in \mathcal{C}^1\left([a,b],\mathbb{R}\right)$.

How can you write down the Euler Lagrange equations associated with this problem?

Comment: As the function is linear in $y$, and there are no constraints, the problem is unsolvable.

Comment: You could try to substitute $z':=y$ or $z(x):=\int_a^x y(s)ds$. Then derive Euler-Lagrange in $z$ and transform back.

Comment: @daw I am actually not focused on the problem itself, rather on the way you can write down the Euler-Lagrange equations for such a functional... if you like you can consider whatever additional constraint which guarantees the existence of a solution; Thanks for your second comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. OP's functional is non-negative
   $$ F[y]~:=~\int_{[a,b]} \!\mathrm{d}x~y(x)\int_{[a,x]}\!\mathrm{d}\xi ~y(\xi)
   ~=~\iint_{[a,b]^2} \!\mathrm{d}x~\mathrm{d}\xi ~\theta(x\!-\!\xi) ~y(x)y(\xi)$$
   $$~=~\frac{1}{2}\iint_{[a,b]^2} \!\mathrm{d}x~\mathrm{d}\xi ~y(x)y(\xi)
   ~\stackrel{(2)}{=}~\frac{G[y]^2}{2} ~\geq~ 0,\tag{1}$$
   where 
   $$G[y]~:=~\int_{[a,b]} \!\mathrm{d}x~y(x).\tag{2}$$
2. The [functional/variational derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative) is
   $$\frac{\delta F[y]}{\delta y(x)}~\stackrel{(1)}{=}~G[y]\frac{\delta G[y]}{\delta y(x)} ~\stackrel{(2)}{=}~G[y]1_{[a,b]}(x),\tag{3} $$
   which is a more general notion than the [Euler-Lagrange derivative](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Euler-LagrangeDerivative.html).
3. OP's sought-for equation is the vanishing of the functional derivative (3). Evidently, a [stationary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_point) configuration $y:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ has 
   $$G[y]~\stackrel{(3)}{=}~0,\tag{4}$$
   which is clearly a minimum (and in particular an [extremum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_and_minima)) for OP's functional (1).

Comment: I would like to learn more about functional/variational derivative; do you have any textbook to recommend?

Answer (score 1):

So the functional to be minimized is
$$\int_a^by(x)\left[\int_a^xy(\xi)\, d\xi\right]dx.$$
I think I would "shift the perspective" a bit from $y$ to $\displaystyle\int y(x)\,dx$. (This is daw's suggestion in the comments above.) That is, let
$$Y(x)=\int_a^x y(\xi)\,d\xi.$$
Then the functional can be written as 
$$\int_a^bY(x) Y'(x)\,dx.$$
Now we let $L=YY',$ and the E-L equations are
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial Y}-\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial L}{\partial Y'}=Y'-\frac{d}{dx}Y=Y'-Y'=0. $$
This procedure at least allows you to write down the E-L equations, even though, in this case, they tell you nothing. I suspect the minimization problem is still ill-defined.

Actually, we can say something more in this particular case:
$$\int_a^b Y(x)Y'(x)\,dx=\frac{Y^2(x)}{2}\Bigg|_a^b=\frac{Y^2(b)}{2}-\frac{Y^2(a)}{2}=\frac{Y^2(b)}{2},$$
by the definition of $Y$.

Minimizing this is tantamount to forcing $Y(b)=0,$ or as close to it as is feasible.

Comment: This trick works fine if you have something like I previously posted, i.e. $y \rightarrow \int_a^b\left[\int_a^xy(\xi)\, d\xi\right]\, dx$; but, honestly, i was looking for a method a bit more robust than this. This is the reason why I edited my original question: now the trick of changing the order of integration doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Hmm. Yeah, I see that. Hang on...

Comment: Well, here's a way to handle the integral - surely this is more robust than what I had before, eh?